# how to include system property in spring boot yml file

Tags: spring-boot, jasypt

I am using application.yml for my spring boot application.  I want to use the password saved in an environment variable within my configuration.  How can i achieve this?

Ex: 
I have an environment variable called "JASYPT_PASSWORD" that contains the password.  I am trying to use it inside my application.yml file.

application.yml:

```
jasypt:
  encryptor:
    password: ${JASYPT_PASSWORD}
spring:
  datasource:
    password: ENC(encryptedpassword+==)
```

If I replace the ${JASYPT_PASSWORD} with the actual password in the above configuration, everything works fine.

I have tried naming the environment variable: JASYPT_ENCRYPTOR_PASSWORD but that does not seem to get pulled in.

Comment: If you have an environment variable called `JASYPT_PASSWORD` what you pasted there should work. Double check your setup.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback @StephaneNicoll. It was a setup issue.

Comment: An alternative was to remove the jasypt: encryptor: password from the application.yml and add an environment variable called JASYPT_ENCRYPTOR_PASSWORD that contains the password.